# How to sequentially update view using threads Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm making an app where I have a row of 3 colored rectangles and have to change the color of each one then revert back to its original color. I have to do this for each rectangle in order so that they do not change colors simultaneously, but in sequence. I've been trying to do this with handlers since I need to wait 1 second before changing it back to its original color, but for some reason it only does the action for a single rectangle rather than all 3. Here's my code:

```
private fun start() {

    val r1: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // Lighting up the rectangle to be white
            val highlightColor = Color.argb(160, 255, 255, 255)
            box.setBackgroundColor(highlightColor)
        }
    }

    val r2: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // Changing back to original color
            box.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7c4dff"))
        }
    }


    var i=0

    while (i<3) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        val tableRow = tableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow
        box = tableRow.getChildAt(i) as TextView

        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        handler.postDelayed(r1, 1000)
        handler.postDelayed(r2, 2000)
        i+=1
    }
}
```

This only lights up the last rectangle rather than a sequence of all 3 in order. How can I fix it so that it lights up the first, then lights up the second once the first reverts back to the original color, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use GlobalScope as it is still a CoroutineScope and you won't have to worry about migrating your project to androidx. Then to delay the thread, just use withContext followed by your delay time, like so below

```
private fun start() {
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

      val boxes = with(tableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow) { 
         (0..2).map { getChildAt(it) } 
      }

      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { delay(800) }
    
      boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(160, 255, 255, 255)) }

      withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { delay(800) }

      boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7c4dff")) }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use GlobalScope, you are leaking the views, just like the solution with no coroutines. There is an article by the team lead of Kotlin coroutines about how you should almost never use GlobalScope. There is also no reason to change dispatchers to call delay. Delay is a suspend function, so it doesn’t block.

Comment: It is possible to create a scope for your activity or fragment that you manually cancel when it is closed to get the same behavior as `lifecycleScope`. Use `MainScope()` to instantiate it, and store it in a property. Then cancel it in `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that your entire while loop that queues up the runnables finishes before they even start running, so they are all looking at the same `box` instance. For this strategy to work, you would either need to create two runnable instances for each of the three boxes, with each of them viewing a different box; or have each of the two runnables have a while loop that goes through all three boxes. You can also use the view to post your runnable so you don't need to create a Handler instance. Like this:

```
private fun start() {
    val boxes = with(tableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow) { 
        (0..2).map { getChildAt(it) } 
    }

    tableLayout.postDelayed(1000L) {
        boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(160, 255, 255, 255)) }
    }

    tableLayout.postDelayed(2000L) {
        boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7c4dff")) }
    }
}
```

This would be simpler using a coroutine like this, which will not leak your views like the Runnables will.

```
private fun start() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    val boxes = with(tableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow) { 
        (0..2).map { getChildAt(it) } 
    }

    delay(1000L)
    boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(160, 255, 255, 255)) }

    delay(1000L)
    boxes.forEach { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7c4dff")) }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both ways and it seems like using coroutines would require me to migrate my project to androidx which I can't currently do. Is there another way I could do this maybe by using a lifecycle observer or some sort? I'm just spitballing.

Comment: Lifecycle is an androidx class as well. I can't imagine writing an Android app in 2020 without using any Jetpack libraries, unless your minSdkVersion is like 29 or 30. Even then, a lot of framework classes and methods are simply deprecated with no replacement except for the Jetpack implementation. What's stopping you from migrating to androidx?